# appcompat 23.2.1 menuitem text small case issue

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-appcompat

I have added appcompat 23.2.1 support library.This library gives menu item text small for lollipop and above version devices but its shows in small case but its not shows in small case for older versions(It shows in capital ).I have used below code for it

[=screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPFuB.png)

```
<style name="Theme.app" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/actionbartop</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionbartop</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
 <style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_textsize_menu</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear what your problem really is?

Answer (score 0):

> you may use , **android:capitalize="none"** in layout

Comment: @JagdishNimbalkar you could use your layout for making all letters in small letter by android:capitalize="non" and             android:textAllCaps="false"